# R case_when not recycling

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to generate number sequence depending on input using case_when function from dplyr package.

I tried the following.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
hahaha <- function(variable){
  
dynamic_var = deparse(substitute(variable))

y_limits = case_when(
    dynamic_var == "Tcore" ~ seq(37.4, 38.2, 0.1),
    dynamic_var == "heart_rate" ~ seq(37.4, 38.2, 0.1),
    dynamic_var == "Tsk" ~ seq(37.4, 38.2, 0.2),
    dynamic_var == "adaptive_psi_score" ~ seq(37.3, 38.2, 0.1)
)

y_limits
}

hahaha(Tcore)
#> Error in `case_when()`:
#> ! Can't recycle `dynamic_var == "Tcore"` (size 9) to match `seq(37.4, 38.2, 0.2)` (size 5).
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. ├─global hahaha(Tcore)
#>  2. │ └─dplyr::case_when(...)
#>  3. │   └─vctrs::vec_size_common(...)
#>  4. └─vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
#>  5.   └─vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
#>  6.     └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
#>  7.       └─rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = vctrs_error_call(call))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I received the above mentioned error message. Does anyone know how can I go about doing it?

Comment: Because the RSH inputs return different lengths, you need to wrap them all with `list()`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thank you! It works! 

i have wrapped all the RHS inputs to list(seq(..)), 
and then supplementing with y_limits[[1]]

Could there be another way to do it more succinctly?

Comment: If you're only passing a single value at a time, consider using `switch()` instead.  This also seems more suited to `case_match()` but you'd still need to wrap the RHS with `list()`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thank you for the suggestion! `switch()` works like a charm for my use case!